# Read, store and print user input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have to get 4 user  input from the user one by one on the next line like

Sample input:

```
65
66
67
68
```

Then the output has to displayed like

```
You have entered:
65-A                                                                  
66-B                                                                  
67-C                                                                   
68-D
```

the program i have return is this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ASCII {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the digits:");
        int no = sc.nextInt();
        char ch= (char) no;
        System.out.println(no + "-" + ch);
    }
}
```

the one thing could not get is the 4 input for the user could someone help with that

Comment: Downvoted and voting to close. You are supposed to show what you have tried so far and explain in detail what exactly is unclear to you. SO is not a code-writing service. See [ask], thanks.

Comment: Create a scanner `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)`. Have a basic for-loop `for (int i = 0; i < 4: i++)` and an array to hold the inputs `String[] inputs = new String[4]` (or a `List<String>`). Read lines in the loop `String line = scanner.nextLine()`. Put them into your array `inputs[i] = line` (or list). Then have another loop that prints all of it `for (String line : inputs)` with `System.out.println(line)`. Done.

Comment: The program I have entered so far is this:import java.util.Scanner; public class AsciValue{

public static void main (String[] args) { Scanner sc new Scanner(System.in); System.out.println("Enter the digits: "); int no = sc.nextInt(); char ch =(char) no; System.out.println(no+"-"+ch);}}

Comment: The only issue I have is I couldn't not 4 user input that is why I asked for help

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and add all the details you can provide. Spend maybe 15 more minutes in improving your question quality, provide everything you have and go into detail about explaning what is unclear to you. Also do research and show your research results. I am sure you will find similar examples online if you google around for like 10 minutes or so. All of this is required before posting on SO, please read [ask], thanks.

Comment: And if you are not familiar with loops and arrays yet and also dont want to take the opportunity to learn them now, you could as well just repeat your code snippet 4 times manually... not nice, but it would work.

Comment: I have add some details is this enough

Comment: Imo it would now qualify for a re-open but I would still downvote it bc you did not adress any of the other things I mentioned: You did no research whatsoever, you did not attempt to solve the "4 inputs" problem at all, you did not attempt to learn about loops/arrays, you did not comment on my "you could as well just repeat your code snippet 4 times manually".

Comment: I have tired and got my answer the  program I have executed is this:.           import java.util.Scanner; public class AsciValue

{public static void main (String[] args) { Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); System.out.println("Enter the digits:"); int no = sc.nextInt(); int no1=sc.nextInt(); int no2=sc.nextInt(); int no3=sc.nextInt(); char ch =(char) no; char ch1=(char) no1; char ch2=(char) no2; char ch3=(char) no3; System.out.println(no+"-"+ch); System.out.println(nol+"-"+chi); System.out.println(no2+"-"+ch2); System.out.println(no3.+"-"+ch3);     }}

Comment: Do you know any source to learn loop in java recommend it

Comment: When I Googled for the terms ___learn loop in java tutorial___ I got 13.5 million results. Surely, at least one of them will help you.

Comment: Asking for learning resources if off-topic at SO. Please familirize yourself with this website and its rules, thanks.

Comment: @Abra Are you really recommending him to traverse 13.5 million results?! Surely he would get help from first few!

Comment: @Abra Oh, come on man! I was just kidding!

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you :

```
public class ASCII {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the digits:");
        int array[]=new int[4];
        for(int i=0; i<4;i++) {
            int no = sc.nextInt();
            array[i]=no;

        }
        System.out.println("You have entered:");
        for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
            char ch= (char) array[j];
            System.out.println(ch+"-"+array[j]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You are recreating scanners inside your loop. That is unecessary and may even result in wrong outcomes due to buffering. Create one scanner and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop it;

```
int[] numbers = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

numbers[n-1] will return number in your case 0 < n < 5;

and you can create another loop to print them.

```
chars[] characters = {'A','B','C','D'};

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(numbers[i]) + characters[i]);
}
```

for loops works like;

```
for (DoAtStart; Condition; DoAtEndOfARepeat) {

}
```